# How to reset svn-properties according to new SVN config?

Tags: svn, automatic-properties

Recently I made a bunch of changes to my local svn config file. Mainly I corrected svn:mime-type properties of about 15 different file types. Now I need reset all previously checked in files according to this new configuration. SVN seems to trigger auto-prop only for ADDs and IMPORTs. So how do I do this without going individually and specifying new mime types?

Thanks!

- dt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to get svn to do this out of the box. The [svn_apply_autoprops.py](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/contrib/client-side/svn_apply_autoprops.py) script should help though.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks clawrence! It worked!

For others FYI, I traced up the source of this script and I found more client scripts:
http://subversion.tigris.org/tools_contrib.html